# Link from navbar to categories

Tags: categories, menus, links

I have a navigation bar in homepage. I don't want show categories in navigation bar.

I also do not want use a dropdown menu. I just want to have a link to a page that show all categories.

[image]

I want when clicked a link in this case categories, my categories show like below:

[image]

but don't know do it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So what exactly do you want. Do you want a dropdown menu containing list of categories or you want to have a page that lists categories? It's not clear, please explain more in you question by [editing it](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/166918/edit)

Comment: tank you, No, I do not want use dropdown menu.i want just have a link to categories. dropdown menu go to category.php but i want a link to a page that show all categories.

Comment: If you want to show a list of categories on a page then I am not sure why you cannot do that. You can create a page to use custom template. Please check the code I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show all categories on a page, you will have to create a new page template.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Categories Page
**/

get_header(); ?>

    <!-- content -->
    <div id="content">

        <ul class="category-list">
            <?php wp_list_categories( 'title_li=' ); ?>
        </ul>

    </div>
    <!-- / content -->

<?php get_footer();
```

Now create a new page for categories in WordPress admin and select this page template `Categories Page` from template list.

And add this page to your menu. That's it.

Of course you will have to create CSS styles for appearances.

Comment: wow...tanx alot. tank you so much... exellent